# Is it possible to set a function disabled while another running in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

My problem is that, the first function loads the full datagridview in my code, and there are several comboboxes, while my WinForm is loading the comboboxes values also load in the Load method.

I have SelectedValueChanged listeners on my comboboxes.

The action listeners are called when the whole form loads when I set theirs values to empty on load function.

Is it possible to enable to run the action listeners when my load function finished?

```cs
// here I want to disable the action listener functions 
private void frmOsszIgenyMegtekintes_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // here I'm loading the DGV and the items in comboboxes also set their values to -1 to make them appear empty 

    // here I want to do something to make the action listeners enabled to run 
}

// I want to disable this permanently 
private void cboxSzuresId_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs) 
{
    if (!cboxSzuresId.SelectedIndex.Equals(-1))
    {
        // this is not relevant just another fuction call
    }
}
```

Comment: Use [synchronization primitives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/overview-of-synchronization-primitives).

Comment: Can you show me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please let me know if I misunderstood you.

You can use one to define a Bool Flag to tell the listener whether it should work.

Examples are as follows:

```
private bool _flagLoading = true;
private void frmOsszIgenyMegtekintes_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 // here I'm loading the DGV and the items in comboboxes also set their values to -1 to make them    appear empty 

//here I want to do something to make the action listeners enabled to run 

    _flagLoading = false;//Set flag to false when it finished
 }

private void cboxSzuresId_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if (_flagLoading) // Check flag before executing any code
    {
        return; //Do nothing
    }

    // Execute event handler code as usual
    else if(!cboxSzuresId.SelectedIndex.Equals(-1))
    {
        //Do what you want
    }
}
```

Comment: It's more simple than my ideas, thank you! By the way I figured it out. In the last rows of the first function a declare the functions and add action listeners to my comboboxes, so when the first function ending it is declaring those like this: this.cboxSzuresUzem.SelectedValueChanged += CboxSzuresKarbantartasiAzonosito_SelectedValueChanged;  and now it is working. Thank you!